# Adding mysql module to php as nonroot

Tags: php

The php on the server is compiled without mysql module so I cannot run mysql_connect in php. I do not have root access. Is there a way for me to solve this problem, perhaps parsing in some files during runtime?

Comment: If you are in a shared hosting environment then ask your provider to enable MySQL... unless you are on a super cheap host they should enable it.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, php does not allow non-root users to include modules.  As already stated, your hosting provider should include it.  Mysql is most likely not installed either.  If they won't give you mysql I'm sure you can find a better host for less than $5 a month.